# Виснет MacOS на виртуальной машине при подключении айфона

Tags: macos, iphone, vmware

Дело выглядит так:

1. Установлена `vmware 14`.
2. Установлена на ней `mac os high sierra`.
3. На мак осе установлен `XCode`.
4. В комплекте также есть айфон последний.

Сначала всё было отлично - код разрабатывался в `Xcode`, всё запускалось. Потом макось взяла и обновилась. `Xcode` по прежнему запускается, все приложения работают но... как только стоит подключить айфон к виртуальной машине всё полностью виснет.  Даже если потом выдернуть айфон из usb разъёма, макось продолжает висеть.

**Вопрос:** подскажите как можно устранить\обойти зависание макоси? Опционально, что может являться причиной зависания?

Answer (score 1):

Была точно такая же проблема. Менял настройки виртуально машины:
"Virtual Machine Setttings -> USB Controller -> USB compatibility".

У меня проблемы возникали если USB compatibility = USB 2.0. Если ставлю USB 3.0 то ОС перестаёт виснуть но самого устройства не видит (у меня ноут старый USB 3.0 в принципе не поддерживает. По этому попробуйте вначале этот вариант). Затем сменил на USB 1.1 и всё заработало (ОС не виснет, устройство видит).

По какой причине возникает проблема и почему именно такое решение не знаю.